# Spring boot Database authentication using Angular

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot as my Rest API and Angular as my front end framework.

I'm a beginner in angular and struggling doing authentication using angular. I have read some articles online but they all are very difficult to grasp.

This is my authentication builder configure method:-

```
     @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
 Exception{
     auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
 }
```

And this is my configuration

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("**/login"))
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/profile").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/","/faq","/donate","/recent","/signup","/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/adduser/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .successHandler(successHandler())
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/profile")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .permitAll();   
}
```

I've successfully implemented user authentication and authorization
using thymeleaf but now I'm trying to implement it in angular for learning purpose.

Should I do JWT authentication (Which includes lot of boiler code in spring)? Is there any other way or alternative solution?

What are the possible ways I can implement this as I can't find any other solution. Please help...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209285/spring-boot-and-security-accessing-secured-url-from-android-app/52211042#52211042

Comment: Do you get any error ? Where is your database configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches, using Oauth or JWT, i prefer JWT for spring boot applications,though the configuration for JWT may be overwhelming.

the most straightforward solution for JWT on Spring boot for your angular app:

[Video tutorial by TechPrimers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HYrUs1ZCLI)

[Source code of the video tutorial](https://github.com/TechPrimers/jwt-security-example)